# How to manually pause and execute for batch of records using map and promises in javascript?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, puppeteer, cheerio

```
function sleep(ms) {
  var start = new Date().getTime(),
    expire = start + ms;
  while (new Date().getTime() < expire) {}
  return;
}

async function executeWithDelay(offers) {
  return Promise.all(
    offers.map((offer, i) =>
      getDetailedInfo(offer).then(data => {
        offer = data;
        if (i % 5 === 0) {
          console.log('executed but it delays now for 3 seconds');
          sleep(3000);
        }
      })
    )
  ).then(function(data) {
    return offers;
  });
}
```

Trying to achieve web-scraping with possible best solution available. I am combining cheerio and puppeteer together and i have some nice code to debug. The above code works fine if the offers data is less i.e 5-10 records. If it exceeds, the browser gets crashed, though i am running in headless version.

This is basically due to in-house bug from the package what i am using which is unable to handle the load. My experiment is to a little delay for every batch of records and complete the full records execution.

But with the below code, it's behaving as non-blocking code and first time it delays and rest is executed constantly.

Should i use for loop instead of map or is there any alternative to handle this situation?

Answer (score 0):

You never want to "sleep" with a busy-wait loop like that. It means nothing else can be done on the main thread.

Once the operations the promises represent have been started, unless they provide some custom means of pausing them, you can't pause them. Remember, promises don't actually *do* anything; they provide a standard way to *observe* something being done.

Another problem with that code is that you're returning `offers`, not the results of calling `getExtendedInfo`.

**If** the problem is calling `getExtendedInfo` too often, you can insert a delay (using `setTimeout`, not a busy-loop). For instance, this does the first request to `getExtendedInfo` almost immediately, the next after one second, the next after two seconds, and so on:

```
function sleep(ms) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

function executeWithDelay(offers) {
  return Promise.all(
    offers.map((offer, i) =>
      sleep(i * 1000).then(getDetailedInfo)
    )
  });
}
```

Obviously, you can adjust that delay as required.

(Note that `executeWithDelay` isn't declared `async`; no need, since it has to use `Promise.all` anyway.)